# How to run Django in Python?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django in python. This is my code.

```
conda create -n djangoenv python=3.8.5 anaconda  
conda activate djangoenv 
conda install -c anaconda django
django-admin startproject website
python manage.py runserver
```

when I run the last line of code I get the following error

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am trying this code

```
(djangoenv) C:\Users\Action>django_project\manage.py
```

and this code

```
(djangoenv) C:\Users\Action>djanago_project\manage.py runserver
```

Both codes are opening the script file, but are not running the Django and giving me the URL

Does anyone have any suggestions to amend the code?

Comment: Do you have an actual Python source file named `manage.py`? According to the documentation, where should it be put? Did you put it there? Did you try following the [quickstart guide from the documentation](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/)? "Does anyone have any suggestions to amend the code?" It's a little difficult to give you any suggestions, because you have not shown us any code; you have only shown us command-line input.

Comment: try running `cd website`    then `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @user14665310 in this case, `cd django_project`, it would seem?

Comment: the question said he ran `django-admin startproject website`

Comment: the file is located here
    C:\Users\Action>django_project\manage.py

Comment: @user14665310 your instructions are working
Thanks!